# UTF-8 not displaying correctly in Cygwin+zsh using ConEmu

Tags: windows-8.1, cygwin, zsh, unicode, conemu

I have installed the following things to use for development:

- ConEmu 15083c
- Recent Cygwin version
- Cygwin zsh-5.0.8
- Oh-My-Zsh
- [This theme](https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train.zsh)

Now, when choosing a theme I realized that the display of special characters is wrong. It looks like this:

```
4:53:04 PM  ~ 
```

Or as a screenshot:

[image]

which totally does not look like it is supposed to:

[image]

I've already followed ConEmu guide on enabling UTF-8 and went through the troubleshooting steps - nothing fixed my issue and all the checks looked good.

Comment: Use proper font. That's all.

Comment: I tried all fonts available in the ConEmu dropdown so I'm not sure what kind of font you're referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use proper font, that's all.**

https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train-oh-my-zsh-theme#requirements

Of course, you will not see "required" font in ConEmu dropdown. ConEmu must not bundle third-party font in its distro.

Also, the font is not required to be installed in the system fonts, as described in [docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/Fonts.html) one may just copy it to ConEmu program folder.

Comment: I just assumed Consolas was ready for everything. That's my fault, sorry. I  wasn't blaming ConEmu. Instead I want to thank you for creating this great application! :)